# Perplexity about an IMO question.

Tags: discussion, moderation, contests

Today and tomorrow [IMO 2015 competition](http://imo2015.org/contestant.php?lang=en) will take place.

I surfing on MSE I have bumped into [the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356083/how-to-solve-this-imo2015) (now closed by author) asking for some help about an IMO 2015 problem. The problem is the competition is taking place during these 2 days.

Well, this leaved me puzzled, so I downvoted the question.

Have I made a good choice and is it a good choice reporting it here?

Comment: tl;dr: Flag the question for moderator attention, preferably including a link to the contest page (with the question and/or the dates of the contest).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think this is somewhat different. IMO is not an online contest or contest where participants submit their solution by snail mail. I am not sure whether Blex is suggesting that somebody leaked the problems from the competition before it started. But since the first session should end about 13.30, local time in Thailand, it should be probably finished by now and, in that case, the problems from that session are now publicly known. (At least to the contestants, I suppose eventually they will appear on the website of the competition.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: The first day of competion may be over but I still don't want to bet if it's ok solving / answering questions until it's completely over. For this reason probably protecting + soft deleting until the end of competition would be ok (then let moderators decide).

Comment: @Blex I did not intend to comment on what should be done with the question. My comment was mainly to the choice to close this post as a duplicate. At the moment we cannot say whether it was indeed question from IMO2015. (Well, the contestants and the jury have the problems from the first day. I do not see them on the contest website yet.) This question is a the moment closed as a duplicate of [this faq question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16774), where one of the mods mentions "Publicly accessible source where we can verify that the question does come from a contest."

Comment: I have [pinged the poster](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334566/solve-the-equation-sigman-n/1334569#comment2757882_1334566) of the question you mentioned. (It is probably good thing to let them know that their post sparked a discussion on meta.)

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. This user has a history of similar eyebrow raising posts and I have been studying the case. This incident is interesting in the sense that it makes it look like the user was **at** the IMO. The moderators are not at liberty of disclosing personally identifying information, but if an IMO official wants to get in touch I can share with them whatever little I can disclose. Flagging the post for moderator attention is probably better than opening a meta thread. IIRC this is the first time we see a question from an ongoing IMO event.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen checking the time-stamps it seems the question was posted slightly less than an hour after the scheduled end of the first session (in any case not at the time a session was on). It seems at least plausible a contestant asked right after the session in which they participated. I do not know the regulations, but this could likely be mostly harmless. Also the fact that the source was mentioned makes it unlikely this is somebody trying to cheat at the IMO.

Comment: Probably no cheating today (cellphones, tablets etc are obviously not allowed at IMO). There may be innocent reasons for everything I've seen, but I am little bit disturbed by some things that have happened earlier (and I take the integrity of math contests a bit too seriously).

Comment: So it seems that it was indeed a problem from IMO2015: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t79529f6h1112743_find_triples_of_integers, http://imo2015.org/solution.php?lang=en, http://www.imo-official.org/problems.aspx

Comment: In the meantime [a new question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356164/finding-a-b-c-with-ab-c-bc-a-and-ca-b-being-powers-of-2) about this problem was posted. (But it is much less problematic now, since at least some time from the problem session have passed.